# DirectX Implementation of Mod Transition

Tags: directx

I need help in implementing MOD transition in DirectX. Two textures are available on which the transition occurs. I was initially thinking about using Pixel Shaders but couldn't proceed.

The details of the MOD transition can be found at the link below:
http://www.stone.com/iMaginator/Manual/Mod.html

Any suggestions on approach would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do pixel shaders not work?

Comment: Pixel shaders work but can't figure out how to proceed (code such an effect)!

Comment: Do you want to make a simple slide or fade in transition or a more advanced like in the link on your post?

Comment: Same as the link in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Since my knowledge of directx shaders is limited (I have not touched direct x in 2 years), I can only give you an example of how I would implement this in opengl.

I would set up 3 textures. The first is the background image, the second is the foreground image (the one the holes are going to be put in), and the third would be a mask image that has only two colors (black and white). I would then draw the background image with a first pass as a fullscreen quad. Then I would draw another fullscreen quad with the two remaining textures (foreground image + mask).

In opengl pixel shaders there is the "discard" command, which lets you discard a pixel. All you need to do then is sample the two textures in your second shader, and if the mask pixel is white, discard the pixel (thus revealing the background), and if it is black, display the texture pixel (from the foreground image).

Then all you need to do is in after the rendering cycle is done, modify the mask texture on the cpu side using some kind of algorithm that progressively makes more and more of the mask texture white.

If directX shaders have something similar to the discard command, you might be able to get this to work. Hope this helps.